# Anyone know what Javascript library is used here?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I was reading an article, and it had an image, and when I clicked on it it had a really interesting way to display the full size. I was wondering if anyone know which javascript library. Here is the link:

http://www.rogueamoeba.com/utm/2009/11/13/airfoil-speakers-touch-1-0-1-finally-ships/

Click the image in the middle of the article.

Cheer!
Shawn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using the FancyZoom plugin, pretty sure cabel.name was the originator of that entire script... http://www.cabel.name/draft1/2008/02/fancyzoom-10.html

As o.k.w pointed out if you are using the jQuery library you can use the jQuery port of it @ http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery_fancy_zoom

Comment: Just to clarify, cabel.name is the originator and there have been ports of it for libraries such as jQuery, etc. I remember when this first came out, it's still nice to this day.

Comment: @meder: I just realised that. Thanks, I've removed my answer about Jquery. :P

Comment: A better jQuery port of FancyZoom can be found at http://orderedlist.com/articles/fancyzoom-meet-jquery. However, the problem with ports of FancyZoom is that they've somehow lost the 'fanciness' of FancyZoom... Neither the port mentioned in the above comments/answer or the one mentioned in this comment have re-created the 'whoosh' zoom effect properly... I'd recommend sticking to the original script, regardless of whether you use a JavaScript library/framework.